# Which maven dependency prevails when I declare two different versions in the same pom file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

This is a real example I stumbled upon.
I am having spring-context artifact with the following declaration (spring.version is 3.2.4.RELEASE):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you check this page http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/3.2.4.RELEASE you will see in the paragraph (This artifact depends on ...) all the dependencies that are imported when you use the declaration above.
One of them is hibernate-validator(4.3.0.FINAL).

Later on , I decide to use another version of hibernate-validator in my pom.xml file (for example because its is newer) and I declare the following code :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it seems that my project is importing two different versions of hibernate-validator.
Which one is being used by the project?
Thank you.

Comment: Your declaration prevails. You could also figure out by using `mvn dependency:list`, see also http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magic word is `distance`: the one closest to your project is used. So if you define it in your projects pom, that one is used. You can also check the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) which has several goals which can show you which version is used in different ways.

Comment: Can I use this plugin from inside IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I'm an Eclipse user, but I'm pretty sure that the integration of Maven within IntelliJ is already good enough to show you the used dependencies. This plugin is primary for cmdline usage, but can also be executed from any IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I found this useful to see the dependencies I use:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

Basically on cmd just type:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

It will show all dependencies of the project.

Type

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=velocity:velocity
```

And it will show only the dependency tree for velocity. (the pattern for the input is groupId:artifactId).